# JavaFX| .setWrapText() does not wrap text in TextArea

Tags: javafx, textarea

I have a TextArea control and I'm trying to make the text wrap, break into new lines whether i'm typing or loading a file's contents into it. My `.setWrapText()` call isn't working and I'm not sure as to why. My structure for my components is `Tab>BorderPane>TextArea` and this is how I create my controls:

```
        Tab newTab = new Tab("New File ");
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        JFXTextArea mainText = new JFXTextArea();
        mainText.prefWidthProperty().bind(borderPane.widthProperty()); //found this somewhere online earlier been on this the whole day and I cant seem to pinpoint the link exactly
        mainText.setWrapText(true);
        borderPane.setCenter(mainText);
        newTab.setContent(borderPane);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you remove the binding does it work?

Comment: @Slaw it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.
I copied text from book to TextArea and setWrapText() didn't work.
Later, i found that escape character /n prevent the method to work.
When I removed them, it worked normally (I think on 85 char in row).

Comment: Hello, please show us a source code how you solved the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).